# Error handling when input is a missing value

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a function like this:

```
def get_output(input_number):
     output = max(7, min(12-0.7*input_number, 12)
     return output
```

I would like to be able to handle the error incase the input number is Nan or None. In that case, the customized error should be thrown to the user that the input value is not a number and execution should stop.

Comment: Yes, do you have an implementation for this?

Comment: Your min-max parentheses () are mismatched. Hopefully that's just a cut/paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming you are talking about numpy NAN.

Additional why do you want to handle exception when you can check it by simple `if`.

```
import numpy as np

def get_output(input_number):
    if input_number is None or np.isnan(input_number):
        raise ValueError("Your message about incorrect value")
    output = max(7, min(12-0.7*input_number, 12)
    return output
```

Here you have simplest solution...

Comment: can i customize thet value error so it just shows the error message and not all the trace back errors?

Comment: I dont think so. You can simply create your own Error.
But if you want to stop further execution you have to raise some error.

Comment: You can also `import sys` and instead of throw an error print message then `sys.exit(1)`.

It would be like:

```if input_number is None or np.isnan(input_number):

    print("Your message about incorrect value")`

    sys.exit(1)```

Comment: StackUser - just for curious, did you check 2th solution? And is it what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can *"try"* this:

```
def get_output(input_number):
    try:
        float(input_number)
        output = max(7, min(12-0.7*input_number, 12)
        return output
    except:
        print("input_number is not a number")
```

Comment: Note that this code silently absorbs the exception, and returns a meaningless `None` to the calling code in case of an exception. So, the calling code can't trust the value returned by this function and has to check it everytime. The good practice is to raise an exception in such a case, that can be handled by the calling code or can cause the program to fail immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
import numpy as np
class MyErr(Exception): pass

def get_output(input_number):
    if (not isinstance(input_number, (int, float)) or 
             np.isnan(input_number)):
        raise MyErr()
    return max(7, min(12-0.7*input_number, 12))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this in two ways.

1. No exception - by using * args

   ```py
   def get_output(*args):
       if args[0]:
           output = max(7, min(12 - 0.7 * args[0], 12))
           return (output)
       else:
           print("the input value is not a number ")


   get_output(None)
   ```
2. Handling exception using try except

```py
def get_output(input_number):
    try:
        output = max(7, min(12 - 0.7 * input_number, 12))
    except TypeError:
        print("input value is not a number")
        return
    else:
        return output

get_output(None)
```

Comment: Note that in both cases, your code silently hides the exception, and returns a meaningless `None` to the calling code instead of a valid number. So, the calling code can't trust the value returned by this function and has to check it everytime. The good practice is to raise an exception in such a case, that can be handled by the calling code or can cause the program to fail immediately